# Truffle migrate not working with 2_deploy_contracts.js

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, ganache, solidity-0.5.x

I have made a sample contract using Truffle's pet-shop. I have also added the 2_deploy_contracts.js file.

I have changed the `solidity version` and also the `constructor() public {}` to comply with the new rules of Solidity.

My Ganache is running parallelly. But, whenever I run the command `truffle migrate`, it returns nothing, so I believe that the command is failing.

The smart contract being used:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.0;

contract Election
{
    string public candidate;
    string public candidate1;

    constructor () public
    {
        candidate = "A";
        candidate1 = "B";
    }
}
```

Migrations.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Migrations {
  address public owner;
  uint public last_completed_migration;

  modifier restricted() {
    if (msg.sender == owner) _;
  }

  constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  function setCompleted(uint completed) public restricted {
    last_completed_migration = completed;
  }

  function upgrade(address new_address) public restricted {
    Migrations upgraded = Migrations(new_address);
    upgraded.setCompleted(last_completed_migration);
  }
}
```

The code for 1_initial_migration:

```
var Migrations = artifacts.require("./Migrations.sol");

export default function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

The code for 2_deploy_contracts.js:

```
var Election = artifacts.require("./Election.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Election);
};
```

I am using:

- Truffle v5.0.4 (core: 5.0.4)
- Solidity v0.5.0 (solc-js)
- Node v8.12.0
- Ganache v1.3.0

Comment: Please share you deployment scripts, the relevant contracts, and your environment details (ganache version, truffle version, etc).

Comment: @goodvibration I have edited my question to add the details. Please have a look.

Comment: Ganache v1.3.0??? Wow, you're like 5 major versions behind man.

Comment: BTW, you forgot to post `1_initial_migration.js` and `Migrations.sol`.

Comment: I didn't post `1_initial_migration.js` and `Migrations.sol` because I didn't modify them from the original pet-shop code. I have added them to the question.
And do you think the ganache version matters?

Comment: Downgrade your Truffle to the latest v4.x (i.e., v4.1.15), upgrade your Ganache to the latest version (v6.2.5 AFAIK), I think you'll find your migration working.

Comment: I did what you suggested. It works like magic. Thanks!